# Cell value was moved x cells below when filtered

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements, highlight

there's a technique which you can use

```
=IF(ISBLANK(search_box),0,SEARCH(search_box,$C5&$D5&$E5&$F5))
```

to automatically highlight the value written in the 'search_box' using conditional formatting. So I have this workbook with a few sheets inside. This formula worked well with 9/10 sheets eccept one. When I typed the value in the search_box, the highlighted cell was in one cell below the typed value.

- You can find the formula instruction [here](https://exceljet.net/tips/how-to-build-a-search-box-to-highlight-data).
- Situation example: I typed: `abc297` and the highlighted value was `abc298` though *abc298* has no relation.
- It is not case sensitive since I have a column of abc(s) and only one cell below the typed value was highlighted.
- I have check my range name, my formula, changes several times, and recheck again for formula mistake but none.
- I have tried to disable all other conditional formats to see if they effected the others but still.
- I have tried to clear format of the cell, duplicate the sheet into new one, or even named different range name to see if my *search_box* name was used before or corrupted, but still.
- When choosing cells to apply this conditional format, I carefully chose other cells than the *search_box*, but still.
- I guess I need someone who has encountered this moving-cell-value problem, but feel free to suggest anything because this worksheet is pretty important to me.

Comment: It means the *row number* your conditional format rule is looking at is incorrect.  So based on your provided information, on your 10th sheet, instead of using row number 5 you'll need to use row number 4: `$C4&$D4&$E4&$F4`

Comment: Either that, or you want the 10 sheets to be identical and the placement of your cells in the 10th sheet are a row off causing the failure.